# how to create a list with static fields in android

Tags: android, list

How can I create a list in android and have static fields declared in the xml file, rather than create an adapter? which is how I would approach a dynamic list

Comment: you can you your strings in strings.xml and populate list from the array

Comment: It is better to read xml file and add to adapter

Comment: set your string in string array and populate it from that array.

Comment: it is impossible to use ListView without Adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define string array inside string.xml file inside res folder as like

```
<string-array name="arrayPaintMenu">
    <item>Circle (Stroke)</item>
    <item>Rectangle (Stroke)</item>
    <item>Circle (Fill)</item>
    <item>Rectangle (Fill)</item>
    <item>Line</item>
    <item>Free</item>
    <item>Text</item>
</string-array>
```

And inside your layout xml declare listview like this

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/arrayPaintMenu" />
```

It will fill ListView automatically you not need to define Adapter for that ...working fine at my side hope you get success...